# Reuse air gapped Raspi used for seed generation?

Tags: wallet-security, seed, raspberry-pi

Would it be wise for an air gapped RasPi used for seed generation be used again online with a new micro SD card? Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Securely wipe it back to factory default.

Even better find an amnesiac live Linux boot image to use.

Most secure though is use an rPi hardware version with no networking at all.

See also Seedsigner.